# How to prevent TraMineR state distribution plot (seqdplot) from removing missing states

Tags: r, sequence, missing-data, traminer

I am analysing some sequence data and wish to be able to see missing states within all of my sequence plots. However, I have noticed that TraMineR's state distribution plot function `seqdplot` automatically removes missing sequence states. I have included a reproducible example below. As you can see, the missing data is visible in the plot and legend of the sequence index plot `seqIplot`. However, it is automatically removed from the state distribution plot `seqdplot`.

How do I stop `seqdplot` from removing these missing values?

**Create & Format Data**

```
# Import required libraries
library(TraMineR)
library(tidyverse)

# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(123)

# Read in TraMineR sample data
data(mvad)

# For loop which generates missing data within the sequences
for (col in 17:86) {
  mvad[sample(1:nrow(mvad),(round(nrow(mvad)*0.1))),col] <- NA
}

# Create sequence object
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86])
```

**Sequence Index Plot (missing data visible)**

```
# Create sequence index plot
seqIplot(mvad.seq, sortv = "from.start", with.legend = "right")
```

[image]

**State Distribution Plot (missing data removed)**

```
# Create state distribution plot
seqdplot(mvad.seq, sortv = "from.start", with.legend = "right")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To display missing values, simply use the argument `with.missing=TRUE`

```
seqdplot(mvad.seq, sortv = "from.start", with.legend = "right",
         with.missing=TRUE, border=NA)
```

By default, `seqdef` sets right missings as voids, i.e., it assumes sequences end at the last valid state. If you want also to treat (display) right missings as missing tockens, set `right=NA` in the `seqdef` command (it is `right="DEL"` by default):

```
mvad.seq <- seqdef(mvad[, 17:86], right=NA)
```